# Ant people polymorphism ( Queen )

Tags: biology, humans, races

***(Perhaps termite people would be more appropriate)***

In my world, the Gbajumo (think race of semi-gods) decide that the humanoid beings of the world have become too cocky and comfortable in their supremacy, and since the current world order of peace and prosperity has gone on for 200 years, it's about time to shake things up. Ideas are pitched, events conspire, and it is decided that ant people need to be created. They work on the reproductive caste first. However, since they are only semi-gods, there are limits to what they can do as far as creating ant people

***Limitations***

- all genetic material must come from Homo sapiens
- the ant people must be achievable by breeding
- all attributes must be possible within 300 millennia of selection

***Prerequisite for "queens"***

- must be able to produce 50 times the maximum amount of children a human female can produce in her lifespan
- must be able to live for at least twice the average humans lifespan (70 years for a human, making 140 for a queen)
- must be able to reproduce throughout her life

Given this information -

What adaptations ofto the human body would be needed to fulfill the requirements for the reproductive caste?

Comment: You mean apart from the obvious breeding of natural triplets with fourlets and gradually selecting those with a long lifespan and better maternal survival? I guess queens would be bigger and stronger (endurance). But what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Oh and breasts. Getting multiple (>2) could prove difficult.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Anything that increases amount of children counts

Comment: Read [Hellstrom's Hive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellstrom%27s_Hive). There are more ways to get genetically alike sisterhoods without thousands of offspring from the same female. Do you really need the 50 times prerequisite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeding of natural triplets with fourlets and gradually selecting those with a long lifespan and better maternal survival.

I guess queens would be bigger and stronger (endurance), so you would have to select those traits too.

Some mutations which only occur by having generations of living humans would probably be necessary as I think not all necessary traits are contained in the current dna pool, so just selecting existing dna could fail.

Other than that, fourlets or more probably need more milk, getting an extra pair of breasts could be really difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the number of births so that multiple births are the norm, 2, 3 or 4 children in one birth, maybe eventually 8 or so.  Shorter gestational period, so shorten 9 months of pregnancy down to say 6.  Shorter recovery for safe return to next pregnancy.  Birth of more males and possibly infertile females vs. fewer very fertile queen females.  Longer lifespan for the queen females, telomeres, etc.